# API data not being fetched with minifyEnabled set to true

Tags: android, proguard

so I have got this weird problem with my app. The app is very small and all it does is:

- it lets user log in, which fires off POST request (OkHttp, Retrofit) to API
- on successful login, API response with image data is sent to the app
- Image data are Base64 encoded, but then decoded and transformed to a bitmap
- Bitmap image is displayed to a user

The API response data class looks like this:

```
data class ImageResponseDto(
val image: String? = null
){
    fun transformStringToBitmap(): Bitmap {
      val decodedString = Base64.decode(this.image, Base64.DEFAULT)
      return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.size)
 }
}
```

Class, to which the response gets mapped to (with an extension function with receiver being the ImageResponseDto class) looks like this:

```
data class ImageResponse(
val imageBitmap: Bitmap
)
```

And the part of code, where the response gets evaluated looks something like this:

```
val response = repository.getImageData(username = username, encryptedPassword = encryptPassword)

    return when (response)
    {
        is Resource.Error -> {
            ...
        }

        is Resource.Success -> {
            val imageResponse = response.data?.toImageResponse()
            GetImageDataResult(
                result = Resource.Success(data = imageResponse?.imageBitmap)
            )
        }
    }
```

Now, thing is, when I use the app in the debug mode, everything works well. Also, when create a release build with minifyEnabled set to **false**, everything works as intended too. However, when I create a release build with minifyEnabled set to **true**, the app crashes on the POST request. I've debugged the APK and the problem is that the data from API is not getting fetched, hence its NULL and then the app crashes when it is trying to Base64 decode the null response.

In my proguard-rules.pro file, I've tried to include the response object class like this:

```
-keep class com.***.data.remote.model.ImageResponseDto
-keep class com.***.domain.model.ImageResponse
```

but the app still crashes. I am using Jetpack Compose, which is the reason I want to use minifyEnabled settings as it increases the performance of the app (even though this app is really small and it doesn't really need it but still).

Thanks in advance for all your suggestions!

Comment: Does it work when you use @Keep annotiation on your data class or add @SerializedName("imageBitmap") before your variable?

Comment: Oh thank you so much man, the Keep annotation did the trick 